# APA style referencing

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I am writing my thesis in LaTeX (to be more specific in Overleaf). For this, I had to refer to articles and do this using APA style. However, I could not find the right way of referencing. 
I already have this settings, that I found on the internet, but still it does not refer to articles the way it should be.

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}.
```

This is an example of the text:

```
Besides this, job resources could buffer the negative impact of high job demands. \cite{bakker2007state}.
```

and the bib:

```
@article{bakker2007state,
  title={The job demands-resources model: State of the art},
  author={Bakker, Arnold B and Demerouti, Evangelia},
  journal={Journal of managerial psychology},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={309--328},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}
```

The in-text references only include the authors, not the year of publication. How should I do this?

And I also have another question. In a sentence like "Research performed by Petrou (2012) shows ...", how should I refer to this article, because when I use `\cite{...}`, everything including the authors name becomes between brackets.

You would really help me and my thesis!

Update

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{a4wide}                     % Tell latex to use the room there is on the page
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % For equation environment
\usepackage[greek, british]{babel}      % Use british hyphenation stuff and the Greek Euro symbol
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   % Nice and shiny headers
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % For images
\usepackage{grffile}                    % So that we can use spaces in image names...
\usepackage{pifont}                     % For ticks and crosses
\usepackage{paralist}                   % Compact enumerate and itemize
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} % Colored text
\usepackage{moreverb}                   % To include keywords
\usepackage{lscape}                     % Landscape page
\usepackage{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{svnkw}                      % SVN revision number (and more) in LaTeX doc.
\usepackage{verbatim}                   % Multiline comments (using \begin{comment}
\usepackage{datetime}                   % For formatting dates
\usepackage{array}                      % To add extra line spaces in tables

%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.35,0.35,0.35}
%\hypersetup{ colorlinks,
%linkcolor=darkblue,
%filecolor=darkgreen,
%urlcolor=darkred,
%citecolor=darkblue }

\usepackage[pagebackref=true,
            colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=gray,
            bookmarks=true,
            filecolor=gray,
            urlcolor=gray,
            citecolor=gray
           ]{hyperref} % Make links clickable and generate bookmarks (so you can easily click through in acroread)
\usepackage{lineno}                   % Include line numbers
\usepackage{longtable}                % Make tables that can cover multiple pages
\usepackage[section]{placeins}        % Prevent floats from passing beyond \FloatBarrier; keep floats within their sections
\usepackage{url}                      % Make it possible to define clickable urls
\usepackage{makeidx}                  % Needed for the index
\usepackage{hyperref}                 % For inserting PDF options (author etc.)
\usepackage{subfig}                   % sub-figures!!! hooray...
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=bottom}   %captions below
\usepackage{booktabs}                 % nicer tables, nice!
\usepackage{rotating}                 % rotated tables and such

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\usepackage{listings}                   % For code formatting
\usepackage{thesis}


\begin{document}

One of the most well-known concepts of increasing social wellbeing is the concept of job crafting, which is defined as an action in which individuals make physical and cognitive changes in the tasks or relational boundaries of their work \cite{wrzesniewski2001}. Employees who take these actions, may increase their work engagement, job satisfaction, resilience and thriving \cite{berg2008}. This process can be described as a bottom-up process, the employee takes the initiative to redesign the job instead of the employer. 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\clearemptydoublepage

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}

\input{appendices/main}

\end{document}
```

And the references in .bib

```
@article{berg2008,
  title={What is job crafting and why does it matter},
  author={Berg, Justin M and Dutton, Jane E and Wrzesniewski, Amy},
  journal={Retrieved form the website of Positive Organizational Scholarship on April},
  volume={15},
  pages={2011},
  year={2008}
}

@article{berg2008,
  title={What is job crafting and why does it matter},
  author={Berg, Justin M and Dutton, Jane E and Wrzesniewski, Amy},
  journal={Retrieved form the website of Positive Organizational Scholarship on April},
  volume={15},
  pages={2011},
  year={2008}
}
```

Comment: Welcome into the community of TeX.SE.

Comment: `apacite` should give you author and year (as required in the APA manual), if you don't get that, something must be wrong. Please show us a short example document that reproduces the undesirable output you get at the moment (a so-called https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 with `\documentclass`, relevant bits of the preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` as well as a few example `.bib` entries). For your second question you may want to try `\citeA` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}. This is an example of the text: Besides this, job resources could buffer the negative impact of high job demands. \cite{bakker2007state}. and the bib: @article{bakker2007state,
  title={The job demands-resources model: State of the art},
  author={Bakker, Arnold B and Demerouti, Evangelia},
  journal={Journal of managerial psychology},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={309--328},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}

Comment: For the second one, it works!! Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant, I got a template that is quite large with different chapters etc.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question! The code shown so far is not quite an MWE in the sense of my links above. An MWE is a *compete* document that starts with `\documentclass`, includes the relevant parts of your preamble (like the `\usepackage{apacite}`) as well as a bit of dummy content between `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Please try to compile the resulting MWE in a new empty folder (or a new Overleaf project) to make sure it reproduces the issue. ...

Comment: ... The advantage of this MWE over snippets of code is that everyone involved can run the same code and the output should be the same for everyone. If we only have snippets, we need to piece them together ourselves and might have to guess, resulting in possibly different documents and outputs. That all said, the code you posted so far looks good. If I put it together to https://gist.github.com/moewew/08f4224498dd2d7a25ae8bfcc1440111 (test it in a new directory/new porject) then output is just as expected with author and year.

Comment: There are quite a lot of packages in your document. Do you really need all of them? A large number of (unused) packages can cause compatibility issues and all sorts of unwanted effects. Packages should also only be loaded once (at least `hyperref` and `color` are loaded twice).

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing can be reproduced in the following small example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bakker2007state,
  title={The job demands-resources model: State of the art},
  author={Bakker, Arnold B and Demerouti, Evangelia},
  journal={Journal of managerial psychology},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={309--328},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Besides this, job resources could buffer the negative impact of high job demands. \cite{bakker2007state}. 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The example throws several errors during complitaion (*never* ignore errors!) and in the resulting output the year is missing in the citation

[image: The citation reads "(Bakker & Demerouti, )."]

This is due to a conflict between `apacite`  and `hyperref`. The `apacite` documentation explains (§8.2 *`hyperref`, `backref`, and `url`*, pp. 47-48)

> These redefinitions have caused severe incompatibility problems between `apacite` and `hyperref` in the past. These incompatibility problems have been solved and `apacite` is compatible with `hyperref`, provided that `apacite` is loaded *after* `hyperref`.

So you should load `apacite` after `hyperref`. (This is contrary what is normally recommended, since `hyperref` should generally be the last package you load.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bakker2007state,
  title={The job demands-resources model: State of the art},
  author={Bakker, Arnold B and Demerouti, Evangelia},
  journal={Journal of managerial psychology},
  volume={22},
  number={3},
  pages={309--328},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Emerald Group Publishing Limited}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Besides this, job resources could buffer the negative impact of high job demands. \cite{bakker2007state}. 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

compiles without errors and produces

[image: "(Bakker & Demerouti, 2007)."]

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you so much, you are my hero!

Comment: @Roos Glad it works, happy TeXing! If you do have some time, though, please consider cleaning out your preamble (see my last comment under the question). Such large lists of packages and packages loaded multiple times are an accident waiting to happen and it is much better to do something about it now while you can than having to scramble to fix things when they blow up hours before a deadline. In general I recommend to load only the packages you know you need. Load as few packages as possible, but as much as necessary to get what you need.